Starting VNC server as a non-root user stops prematurely
It is about a Ubuntu 22.04 XFCE subsystem in a proot'ed environment Andronix under Termux on an Android 14 cellphone. The 'real' root (for a rooted Android) is NOT used, when I write about 'root', it is the virtual root of the proot subsystem.
I post this on 'superuser' as this is not an Android issue, but a generic Linux / VNC issue.
When I run a VNC server I can get a VNC as root and can connect with a VNC server normally.
But I want to use it as non root user, so I created a user and made a home folder /home/user in the virtual prooted file system.
So I used the same vncserver-start command (see below) after running su -c user to get the nonroot user environment.
It succeeded after installation and then I configured the local environment of the 'user' in the xfce environment, logged out.
Then I restarted the VNC server under the same user and then it failed with a VNC server error, so it is not a fouled user environment.
This is how the VNC server is started:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export USER=user   
export HOME=/home/user
su -c `vncserver -fg -name remote-desktop -geometry 1920x1080 -localhost yes :1` $USER

I have to su into the user account, as the proot itself opens as a root user.
But the output is:
=================== tail /home/user/.vnc/localhost:5901.log ===================
[mi] mieq: warning: overriding existing handler (nil) with 0x30001531e0 for event 2
[mi] mieq: warning: overriding existing handler (nil) with 0x30001531e0 for event 3
X connection to :1 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).

Sat Apr 20 08:58:58 2024
 ComparingUpdateTracker: 0 pixels in / 0 pixels out
 ComparingUpdateTracker: (1:nan ratio)
Killing Xtigervnc process ID 8381... success!
================================================================================

Session startup via '/etc/X11/Xtigervnc-session' cleanly exited too early (< 3 seconds)!

Maybe try something simple first, e.g.,
    tigervncserver -xstartup /usr/bin/xterm
The Xtigervnc server cleanly exited!
The X session cleanly exited!
VNC server started. The default password is the account password for user
user@localhost:~$ 

However, when I replace 'user' by 'root' and '/home/user/' by '/root', it works.
And when I simplify the script with
#!/usr/bin/env bash
vncserver -fg -name remote-desktop -geometry 1920x1080 -localhost yes :1

it works as well as I don't need the su -c '<command>' root` for root itself.

Possible problem: If the non-root user's PATH does not include /home/username it will default to root's files.
